# Perl to Python regex help needed

Tags: python, perl

I am new to Python regex, and did not find enough info for how to do this in Python

Perl:

```
my $a="some pattern";
my $b="some other pattern";
my $str =~ s/\s*$a\s+\-\-\>\s+$b/ $b/;
```

$a and $b change, and the specific strings need to be substituted.
Any idea how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
a = "some pattern"
b = "some other pattern"
# Create the regular expression. '-' and '>' don't need escaping
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*' + a + '\s+-->\s+' + b)
# 'str' is a poor variable name in Python; it hides a built-in
result = pattern.sub(' ' + b, result)
```

Although I don't really know how you could fail to find enough information, assuming you actually understand how regexes work. Did you read the documentation?

There is no equivalent to Perl's /o flag; if you want to compile a regular expression once and re-use it, then... do exactly that; play with the scope of `pattern` so that the `re.compile` line is only run once.